# RetroPie not detecting my ROMs even after tweaking settings in ~/.emulationstation/es_settings.cfg

Tags: retropie

I went through the following process to install RetroPie (more or less as described in [this post](http://supernintendopi.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/an-a-to-z-beginners-guide-to-installing-retropie-on-a-raspberry-pi/)):

1. Downloaded the image [here](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/retropie-downloads/) and then copied it over to my SD card
2. Booted it up, configured it for wifi, and then ran `sudo raspi-config` to configure the file system expansion (option 1), internationalization (option 4), enabled SSH, and 256 memory split (both under option 8; I have a Model B).
3. `scp`ed over some ROMs to the correct folders under `~/RetroPie/roms`; for example, I copied over a Chrono Trigger rom ending in `.smc` under the `snes/` folder.
4. Rebooted it and started EmulationStation.

Except now I'm getting to the Linapple 2 screen, and yes, [I've tried using the arrow keys to navigate between the emulators](http://blog.petrockblock.com/forums/topic/retropie-linapple-very-confused/), but it doesn't work.

I've also tried editing the snes entry for `~/.emulationstation/es_systems.cfg` from this (the initial configuration):

```
DESCNAME=Super Nintendo
NAME=snes
PATH=/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/snes
EXTENSION=.smc .sfc .fig .swc .SMC .SFC .FIG .SWC
COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/supplementary/runcommand/runcommand.sh 1 "retroarch -L /home/pi/RetroPie/emulatorcores/pocketsnes-libretro/libretro.so --config /home/pi/RetroPie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg --appendconfig /home/pi/RetroPie/configs/snes/retroarch.cfg %ROM%"
# alternatively: COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/emulators/snes9x-rpi/snes9x %ROM%
# alternatively: COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/emulators/pisnes/snes9x %ROM%
PLATFORMID=6
```

To this:

```
DESCNAME=Super Nintendo
NAME=snes
PATH=/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/snes
EXTENSION=.smc .sfc .fig .swc .SMC .SFC .FIG .SWC
# COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/supplementary/runcommand/runcommand.sh 1 "retroarch -L /home/pi/RetroPie/emulatorcores/pocketsnes-libretro/libretro.so --config /home/pi/RetroPie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg --appendconfig /home/pi/RetroPie/configs/snes/retroarch.cfg %ROM%"
COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/emulators/snes9x-rpi/snes9x %ROM%
# alternatively: COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/emulators/pisnes/snes9x %ROM%
PLATFORMID=6
```

And this:

```
DESCNAME=Super Nintendo
NAME=snes
PATH=/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/snes
EXTENSION=.smc .sfc .fig .swc .SMC .SFC .FIG .SWC
# COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/supplementary/runcommand/runcommand.sh 1 "retroarch -L /home/pi/RetroPie/emulatorcores/pocketsnes-libretro/libretro.so --config /home/pi/RetroPie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg --appendconfig /home/pi/RetroPie/configs/snes/retroarch.cfg %ROM%"
# alternatively: COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/emulators/snes9x-rpi/snes9x %ROM%
COMMAND=/home/pi/RetroPie/emulators/pisnes/snes9x %ROM%
PLATFORMID=6
```

But neither configuration helps detect the ROM. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, never mind, I'm a doofus.

So there was nothing wrong with my `es_systems.cfg` file at all; I was just trying to navigate between emulators on the wrong screen. *facepalm*

I was trying to do that on this screen:

[image: wrong screen]

When I should've been trying to navigate left and right on *this* screen instead:

[image: right screen]

*sigh*

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds themselves here, I also had this problem but the fix was not so simple for me.

In my case, after reviewing the es_systems.cfg file I noted that the file extensions list for my emulator did not include ".ZIP" which is how all of my roms are stored.  Once I unzipped them and moved them into the appropriate roms folder on the Raspberry Pi, the emulator picked them up and they worked.  This was the same for every emu I tried.